# Should I map both sides of bidirectional relations in EF code first?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Assume I have the following entity classes:

```
public class Customer {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

How should those be mapped in Entity Framework 6 fluent code-first mapping? I want to be explicit about the mapping and not rely on automatic mapping conventions.

### Option 1

Just map the local properties of both classes. That's how I would do it in Fluent NHibernate.

```
public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer> {
  public CustomerMap() {
    HasMany(x => x.Orders);
  }
}

public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order> {
  public OrderMap() {
    HasRequired(x => x.Customer);
  }
}
```

### Option 2

Map both sides of the relationship in both classes.

```
public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer> {
  public CustomerMap() {
    HasMany(x => x.Orders).WithRequired(x => x.Customer);
  }
}

public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order> {
  public OrderMap() {
    HasRequired(x => x.Customer).WithMany(x => x.Orders);
  }
}
```

### Option 3

Map both sides of the relation, but only in one of the classes. The code would be similar to option 2, just one of the two constructors would be empty.

---

Is there any difference between those options? If yes, please also explain why I should or shouldn't use a specific option.

Comment: EF will detect a onet-to-many relation between this two classes automatically, you don't need to define extra mapping.

Comment: @Masoud Added the note to the question that I don't want to rely on conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for **option 3**.

In option 1 you can forget to map the inverse end of an association. In this simple example it's clear that `Order.Customer` and `Customer.Orders` are two ends of the same association. When things get more complex, this isn't always obvious. Also, it is redundant code.

In option 2 you could have conflicting mappings. For instance when you have...

```
HasOptional(x => x.Customer).WithMany(x => x.Orders);
```

...in `OrderMap`, you will get a runtime exception telling you that both mappings don't match. And again, it is redundant code.

So option 3 is DRY and safe. The only issue is that it's a bit arbitrary where to configure the mappings. I tend to adhere to mapping children in their parent's mapping.

One more comment. You may want to add a primitive property `CustomerId` in `Order`. The mapping would look like:

```
public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Orders).WithRequired(x => x.Customer)
                              .HasForeignKey(o => o.CustomerId);
    }
}
```

Now you have full control over both ends of the association and the foreign key name to be used. Besides that, there are some advantages of these *foreign key associations* as opposed to *independent associations* (without a primitive foreign key property). For instance, the ability to establish an association without having to fetch the parent object from the database. You can just by set an Id value.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, but it seems like you focused on coding style. How about runtime behavior? Is it exactly the same?

Comment: Well, I pointed out that option 2 can throw a runtime exception. For the rest it doesn't matter. There are several ways to configure mappings that, in the end, result in exactly the same mapping, so the runtime won't notice any difference.

Comment: Of course the shape of the mapping itself *does* matter. Whether or not to use foreign key associations can make a difference in start-up time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx (see: 2.4.1 Using Foreign Key Associations to reduce view generation cost).

Comment: I've now found out that option 1 results in a different mapping if all conventions are removed from the context. Seems like in that case EF can't figure out that they are the two ends of the same association. I'm still undecided between option 2 and 3. Option 2 has the advandage of being more explicit. The exception that is thrown for a wrong mapping is also an advandage in my opinion. But Option 3 respects DRY. But that's a coding style question which doesn't belong to SO. Thanks for your help.