# Entity Framework : should I provide double-side relationship configuration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My question is very simple : here I have two classes with one-to-many relationship. 
Let's take a sample : 
 *Sample taken from book of Julia Lerman "Programming Entity Framework : Code First"*

```
public class Destination
{
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[]  Photo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }

    public Destination()
    {
        Lodgings = new List<Lodging>();
    }
}

public class Lodging
{
    public int LodgingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public bool IsResort { get; set; }
    public decimal MilesFromNearestAirport { get; set; }
    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
}
```

And here configurations with FluentApi :

```
public class LodgingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Lodging>
{
    public LodgingConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
        HasRequired(p => p.Destination).WithMany(p => p.Lodgings);
    }
}

public class DestinationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Destination>
{
    public DestinationConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        Property(p => p.Description).HasMaxLength(500);
        Property(p => p.Photo).HasColumnType("image");
        HasMany(p=>p.Lodgings).WithRequired(l=>l.Destination);
    }
}
```

I suppose that lines

```
HasRequired(p => p.Destination).WithMany(p => p.Lodgings);
```

and

```
HasMany(p=>p.Lodgings).WithRequired(l=>l.Destination);
```

*provide the same result on relationships between Destination and Lodging.*

If I define only one of this rules, it works well too.
Is it a good practice to define the same rule on both sides or is one-side declaration is Ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the results if you do `add-migration` for the three variants:

> With mappings in Lodging and Destination Configuration Types

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Lodgings",
        c => new
            {
                LodgingId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
                Owner = c.String(),
                IsResort = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                MilesFromNearestAirport = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                Destination_DestinationId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.LodgingId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Destinations", t => t.Destination_DestinationId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.Destination_DestinationId);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Destinations",
        c => new
            {
                DestinationId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                Country = c.String(),
                Description = c.String(maxLength: 500),
                Photo = c.Binary(storeType: "image"),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.DestinationId);

}
```

> Removing mapping from Lodging Configuration Type

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Lodgings",
        c => new
            {
                LodgingId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
                Owner = c.String(),
                IsResort = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                MilesFromNearestAirport = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                Destination_DestinationId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.LodgingId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Destinations", t => t.Destination_DestinationId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.Destination_DestinationId);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Destinations",
        c => new
            {
                DestinationId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                Country = c.String(),
                Description = c.String(maxLength: 500),
                Photo = c.Binary(storeType: "image"),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.DestinationId);

}
```

> Removing mapping from Destination Configuration Type

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Lodgings",
        c => new
            {
                LodgingId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
                Owner = c.String(),
                IsResort = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                MilesFromNearestAirport = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                Destination_DestinationId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.LodgingId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Destinations", t => t.Destination_DestinationId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.Destination_DestinationId);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Destinations",
        c => new
            {
                DestinationId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                Country = c.String(),
                Description = c.String(maxLength: 500),
                Photo = c.Binary(storeType: "image"),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.DestinationId);

}
```

As you can see, the generated code (Sql server in this case) is exactly the same. It's always a matter of style and to be consistent. You could explicitly set the mappings for the children in the parent configuration type or any other styles.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907788/should-i-map-both-sides-of-bidirectional-relations-in-ef-code-first) is a very good answer about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Both configurations are perfectly fines. It is a good practice if you really need it. If not keep the relation simple and only expose the navigation property in the Entity that has sense. (It is more a problem related to your entity models than EF)

Answer (score 1):

Only define it once (e.g.)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired<Course>(s => s.Course)
    .WithMany(s => s.Students);
```

Remember you need to maintain your code. Having the same information in two separate representations/locations is a recipe for a bug. Do you think everyone on your team would be that meticulous?